# Rotated table in Latex appears at the end of the file

Tags: rotation, latex

Any table I define with "sidewaystable" appears at the last page of created pdf file. How can I solve this?

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[h]
\caption{Blah Measurements}
\centering % centering table
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c}
\hline\hline % inserting double-line

A & B & \multicolumn{3}{c}{C} & C Time + & D & \multicolumn{3}{c}{D Signal} \\
ID & ID & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Coordinates} & Time Diff. & Time & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Parameters} \\ [0.5ex]

\hline % inserts single-line
1 & 1 & 4415633.126837 & 482211.909079 & 939.450000 & 06:07:40 & 06:07:40 & -85 dBm & 6 dB & 5 dBm \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:combined}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried the something like `htbp` for the placement of the float object?

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[htbp]
...
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: Yes; the problem is that if a table is too big then `h` is inappropriate, and the table will float to a page of its own, which is usually much later (perhaps the end) in the document.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I have pasted your code example in a LaTeX document with ~10 pages output and in my case the placement using the htbp option was at the correct position.

Comment: The p is important. It is not part of the default which is why your tables are floating to the end. Just make sure you include it and the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Just use \clearpage \newpage before \begin{sidewaystable} and \clearpage after the \end{sidewaystable}..

It works without any floats like H, h!, htpb, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can try and use \begin{table}[h!] -- the ! will try and tell latex to force your table into the exact spot. I've had hit or miss results.

Also, with the float package, you can use a capital H \begin{table}[H] to keep your table from floating.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, too. ! did not work; table was still at the end of file. H made the table disappear completely :)

Comment: did you add the float package to your preamble?
Like this : \usepackage{float}

The float package provides the H, so if you don't have the float package, your table will disappear.